# Bind Values to GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a List with following values

```
 List<Calculations> calcs = new List<Calculations>();
 Calculations cal = new Calculations();
    cal.TotalTotalC2 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["TotalTotalC2"].ToString());
     cal.TotalTotalC3 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["TotalTotalC3"].ToString());
     cal.TotalC1C4IOM = Convert.ToInt32(reader["TotalC1C4IOM"].ToString());
    cal.TotalC1C4MDR = Convert.ToInt32(reader["TotalC1C4MDR"].ToString());
calcs.Add(cal);
```

i need to Bind these Numeric values in the following table format.left hand side plain text and right hand side the bound values.

[image]

Can some one plz tell me that how can i use GridView to bind in above format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to dynamically generate a DataTable and then bind it to GridView

```
   DataTable dt=new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));

 foreach (Calculations item in calcs )
        {
    dt.Rows.Add("Total ...", item.TotalTotalC2);
    dt.Rows.Add("Total ...", item.TotalTotalC3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to write code in RowDataBound event , and check for row number in each iteration and based on the row number bind the column text of your custom list to the column, I don't think there is any auto function to bind column names to grid!!! let me know if you find something direct and easy